# Message selector with receiveNoWait()

Tags: java, jms, selector, ibm-mq

Will message selectors work with receiveNowait() method too for synchronous process. it works with receive() method but wanted to know for receiveNoWait for IBM mq.
Message selector is added while creating consumer.

EDIT 1:
I have tested with receiveNowait() method, and the selector is not working. I don't know the problem is with my selector or the receivenowait method. following is the selector I have used:

```
String messageSelector = "JMSTimestamp <= " + System.currentTimeMillis() - 180000;
 receiver = (MessageConsumer) session.createConsumer(replyQueue, messageSelector);
```

that means, receiver has to receive the messages only which are 3 minutes older than current time.
Can anyone figure out what is the issue.

EDIT 2:
after complete testing , i have found that problem is with selector, what can be the correct usage of JMSTimeStamp in selector expression?

Comment: ...have you tried it?   Is there anything in the knowledge center that would indicate it will not work?

Comment: JoshMc there is nothing in knowledge center but haven't found even a single example on it so had a doubt. I am going to try it now. Will see whether it works or not.

Comment: As @JustinBertram noted, I see no reason it would not work.

Comment: Selector is not working with receiveNoWait according to my test results. I will update the code in sometime

Comment: If you use `receive()` or `receive(long)` does the selector work as you expect?

Comment: no its not working, tested just now. problem is with selector. Cant we use JMSTimeStamp the way I used

Comment: Hi Harsha, with regard to the original question I think it has been answered, the right think to do is to accept one  of the answers.  With regard to your "EDIT 2", remove that from this question and open a new question on that subject, this is a one question one answer site, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pepared The system.currnetTimeMillis() value is not updated when the selector is run.

Here you are fixing the "current" timestamp when you initialize the selector.
You should do a query like "endValidityDate <= (JMSTimestamp-24*60*1000)" for your query (same problem than any SQL query with fixed values instead of dynamic ones).

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the IBM MQ implementation specifically, but from a JMS perspective there's nothing in the JMS specification that limits the use of selectors with `receiveNoWait` so I would expect it to work in any compliant implementation.

Comment: I have edited my question, added the selector code, please check

Answer (score 0):

receive(), receive(long timeout) and receiveNoWait() should work exactly the same in terms of what is delivered. In fact several implementations implement one by calling another method.

Comment: I have edited my question, added the selector code, please check

Comment: did you ever get it to work with MQ JMS ? I've tried but I don't see that working. Maybe a bug in MQ JMS ? I had this output: selector: JMSTimestamp < 1552325982237
JmsConsumer: waiting for message....
received: JMSTimestamp:     1552326165700

Comment: Yeah it's not working, I tried using BETWEEN operator as well, it's working differently