# MQ message selector with JMSTimestamp

Tags: java, jms, selector, ibm-mq

I have created an MQ receiver with following selector:

```
String selector = "JMSTimestamp BETWEEN 1446297200000 AND 1552479882777"
```

When I ran the code, the selector is picking up the messages which is out of these bounds and it is not picking up the ones which are actually supposed to be picked up.
Log snippet is as written below :

```
**lines****
--------- Receiving messages from MQ.
--------- Created consumer with Message selector JMSTimestamp BETWEEN 1446297200000 AND 1552479882777.
--------- Receiving messages.
--------- Message type is text.
--------- JMSTimestamp is 1552480011190.
--------- JMSTimestamp with format Mar 13,2019 13:26:51 .
--------- Processing Message.
***lines***
```

As we can see in logs the JMSTimeStamp of message is greater than the one mentioned in selector upper bound 1552479882777.

what is wrong in the selector, and how is it supposed to be written? please help to analyse.

Full code is as follows:

```
      @Cleanup
      QueueConnection connection = null;
      @Cleanup
      QueueSession session = null;
      @Cleanup
      MessageConsumer receiver = null;
      @Cleanup
      InitialContext ctx = null;
      ctx = new InitialContext();
      QueueConnectionFactory cf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
      connection = (QueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
      session = (QueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      log.info("Receiving Message from MQ");
      Queue replyQueue = (Queue) session.createQueue(REPLY_QUEUE);
      //getting time till 3 minutes ago
      Long threeMinutesAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() - 180000;
      // below expression is to select messages which are sitting in queue for more than 3 minutes,
      String messageSelector = "JMSTimestamp BETWEEN 1446297200000 AND " + threeMinutesAgo;
      receiver = (MessageConsumer) session.createConsumer(replyQueue, messageSelector);
      log.info("created Consumer with message selector {}", messageSelector);
      connection.start();
      while (true) {
        log.info("------------receiving response--------------");
        Message asyncMessage = receiver.receiveNoWait();
        if (asyncMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
          log.info("Message type is text");
          log.info("JMSTimeStamp is {}", String.valueOf(asyncMessage.getJMSTimestamp()));
          log.info("JMSTimeStamp with format {}", sdf.format(new Date(asyncMessage.getJMSTimestamp())));
          log.info("ThreeMinutesAgo with format {}", sdf.format(new Date(threeMinutesAgo)));
          log.info("Difference is {}", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - asyncMessage.getJMSTimestamp()));
          log.info("Difference with format {}",
              sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - asyncMessage.getJMSTimestamp())));
          String replyString = ((TextMessage) asyncMessage).getText();
          asyncMessage.acknowledge();
          processIntoText(replyString);
        } if (asyncMessage == null) {
          log.error("Queue is now empty for specified messages or null. ");
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (JMSException | JAXBException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | NamingException e) {
      log.error("Error in messaging {}", e);
    }
```

Comment: The syntax of the selector looks OK to me.

Comment: It's not working still

Comment: Have you tried using an alternative syntax like `JMSTimestamp >= 1446297200000 AND JMSTimestamp <= 1552479882777`? If that also doesn't work then I'd suspect a bug in your JMS client or server.

Comment: Yeah even this doesn't work

Comment: We are using Mq version 7.5, does it has any flaws which is fixed in later version?

Comment: You selector looks ok, which implies that maybe there is a bug in how your code applies the selector to the message consumption. You have only provided the system output from your app, and not the code, so it is difficult to tell.

Comment: I have added the full code .. please check.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023274/message-selector-with-receivenowait/55039020#55039020 - the same issue it seems. Maybe a bug in MQ JMS ? I had this output with selector: JMSTimestamp < 1552325982237 JmsConsumer: waiting for message.... received: JMSTimestamp: 1552326165700

Comment: Have you tried posting question in IBM forum? I am going to test with upgraded version now.

Comment: I have upgraded mq version to 9 , still it doesnt work